# Literature Request: Koszul-Tate Resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, reference-request, homology-cohomology

Good people!

So, these papers that have become incredibly relevant to me all keep using these things called *Koszul-Tate resolutions*, which I must admit was not part of my training. I know about resolutions of modules and their use in (co)homology from Grillet and Hatcher, but, Mssrs. Koszul and Tate's names never figured there, I'm afraid. When I google online, the best stuff I can find are Koszul's and Tate's original articles, which are a tad too technical for my comprehension, and uses nomenclature a little out of date, as well as later articles going into extensions and generalizations quite beyond the scope of what I'm looking for.

Frankly, all I need to know is, say you have a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ in that ring, then how do you properly construct the Koszul-Tate resolution in terms of the exterior powers of increasing order? Where do you find all that explained?

I was hoping that one (or several) of you might recommend some good textbook for a simple graduate student, explaining how it all fits together in a neat and nice way, preferrably with a couple of easy examples.

Would that be possible?

I look forward to what you have to offer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with the usual Koszul resolution, a purely classical (as opposed to derived) treatment is in Eisenbud-Harris's Commutative Algebra. You might also look at Toen's EMS survey paper on derived algebraic geometry for his example of Euler classes of vector bundles. A good example to compute on your own would be something like the self-intersection of the origin in $\mathbb{A}^1$ or $\mathbb{A}^2$.